# PIC32MX460F256L connection concern

Tags: pic, programming, jtag

I've recently aqquire a board which have an embedded PIC32MX460F256L of a project and working on. Nonetheless I'm not being able to connect to connect the MCU to my desktop even when I used MPLAB ide.

When I received the board I've been told that with only the USB cable connecting directly to the computer I'ld be able to flash the MCU. I also have the microhip driver for the MCU but shen I try to install it in windows 10 it gives me a signature error.

I know the MCU is wirking because everytime I connect it to the laptop it makes the sound, nonetheless I can't see it either in the device manager when its plugged in, therefore I think it should be a driver issue.

Does anyone is having this issue and is not being able to flash a pic or is it another way to flash the PIC32MX460F256L?

Comment: `therefore I think it should be a driver issue.` Okay so have you installed the correct driver?

Comment: Another way is to use the ICSP module and a Pickit if you can get your hands on one and the board was set up so that you can get the right pins (MCLR, VDD, GND, PGED, PGEC). That is what I use, might be something check. Then you just program through the MPLAB IDE, making sure you have the XC32 compilers.

Comment: I've found the correct drive and tomorrow I will try to flash via ICSP, thanks so much for your help